# How do I add a new jquery.easing declaration in .d.ts file

Tags: next.js, react-typescript

I want to use jquery.easing in next.js typescript project. But when I import "jquery.easing";
Declration in a .tsx component file, It thorw an error:

> add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jquery.easing';`

How can I do that ?
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Have you installed [@types/query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery)?

Comment: unfortunately not found

Comment: What do you mean not found?

Comment: I mean package is not found in npm packages

Comment: You can install it using `npm i -D @types/jquery`

Comment: unfortunately after install package, when I run project , it throws an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'swing')